# Committing a file that has not been checked out

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to SVN having used SourceSafe and a home-brew solution for many years.

We've all done it, I have many edited files that were not checked out first.  Is there a way I can either:

1. Force a commit despite the file not being checked out
2. Checkout without overwriting my altered files
3. Another approach?

I use TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If either of the answers worked for you please Accept the answer by clicking the tick mark next to it. If neither helped please provide more info. Also, be sure to read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The short story is check out a new working copy to get an .svn folder which is up to date, and then replace the folder contents with your local active working copy, and commit the difference.*

---

If the file you added locally is exactly the same as the version which has been added to the svn repository, and the file is text (i.e. not binary), just do an `svn update` and the local file will be "versioned" (recognised as being present and correct at the current repository version level) by svn.

If the local file is different and is text, an `svn update` should again version the file, after which you can `svn commit` your change.

If in doubt, make a local copy of your versioned folder first then see what happens. You can do no harm if you have a backup.

The safest approach, however, is to check out a new copy of the folder in question. Then delete everything from that folder (NOT `svn delete`!) apart from the `.svn` folder. Since you have TortoiseSVN you're presumably using Windows, so what I mean here is in Explorer, select everything except for `.svn` and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Then copy your working files and folders into the folder and commit the changes. You might wonder how this works - the `.svn` folder contains a pristine copy of the files as they exist in the remote repository and so is able to compare your local working files and folders to work out what has changed.

When you [commit](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html) be sure to tick the box "Show unversioned files" to include any new files created locally which aren't versioned yet, and then click "All" to include all changes including any new files in your commit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SourceSafe and SVN use different terminology. What you call a "checkout" in SourceSafe is called **locking** a file in SVN.

But SVN doesn't (usually) require that you lock files to work on them because it uses an optimistic locking method. That is, it assumes that files will be merge-able upon commit. This usually works for plain text files, and in cases where two people have changes to the same portion of the same file, a manual merge will be required.

This is a **much** better way to work than VSS's model because it means that you can't get locked out of a file when someone else goes on vacation.

You really ought to read [Part I of the Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.content.html) to make sure you understand the operational model of Subversion. If you try to use it like VSS, it's going to hurt.

With Subversion a "checkout" is just pulling a copy of a portion of the repository to your workstation to make changes in. It does not change the state of the repository, nor does it exclusively lock files for your use.

So your operation should be:

1. Check out a working copy (if you already have one, update it instead)
2. Make your changes
3. Commit
4. Repeat

Comment: Yes I do understand the differences and in fact it's a while since I used VSS, my main recent experience is the home brew, a combination of release folders and Arraxis!  The problem is that my changed files are in a folder that hasn't been checked out from SVN to.  Therefore, in Tortoise, when I righ click on my changed file I don't get the Commit option.

Comment: Then you need to check out a working copy, move your changes into it, then commit (it's possible to check out into the existing folder but it can be risky). The system you're using right now sounds like a recipe for confusion and lost/corrupted work.

Comment: Yes this this is the approach I used.  The situation was transitory and I'm now working from checked out folders.  For anyone else that stumbles across this I can confirm that you can delete the checked out file with impunity and copy in an alternative file.